# Cronjob Running on the Hour (not anticipated)

Tags: centos, cron

I have a cronjob I want to run every 17 minutes and it does, but it also runs on the hour. How do I keep it from running on the hour (example 13:00)?

CRON:

```
*/17 * * * * php script.php
```

CRON LOG:

```
Aug 10 16:17:01 CROND[1925]: CMD (php script.php)
Aug 10 16:34:01 CROND[1126]: CMD (php script.php)
Aug 10 16:51:02 CROND[1197]: CMD (php script.php)
Aug 10 17:00:01 CROND[1130]: CMD (php script.php)
```

Comment: @Rahul changed my wording to "on the hour" to be more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking it to run every multiple of 17 minutes, every hour, which is what it is doing (zero is a multiple of seventeen).  If you want it to run only at :17, :34 and :51, try

```
17,34,51 * * * *    php script.php
```

If you want it to run every seventeen minutes, you'll need to instead use `* * * * *` and add the time-checking logic to your command.

Comment: When you refer to my command, are you talking about script.php or part of the cron command?

Comment: @JMC, either works in theory.  In practice, calculating if *now* is an even multiple of 17 minutes since *arbitrary startpoint* would be much uglier on the cron command line then hidden in a function in your script.

Comment: It's not *that* bad in shell (e.g., in crontab); something like `[ $(expr $(date +%s) / 60 % 17) -eq 0 ] && job` should do it. You can change the 0 to 0…16 to configure which minute its executed (0 would be at the epoch, 1 would be 1 minute later, etc., and every 17 minutes thereafter)